# Why was F-Spot replaced with Shotwell in Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: f-spot, shotwell, 10.10

What are the advantages of using Shotwell? What are the disadvantages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The specification for this decision is [here](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-maverick-shotwell)

[Here (Sorry, this show has been removed from Blip.)](http://ubuntudevelopers.blip.tv/file/2876109/) is a video clip where we discussed Shotwell (and other apps) at the Ubuntu Developer Summit.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially the choice was made upstream (by Gnome). But there are a lot of advantages:

- No Mono
- It's lightweight and crash free
- Better integrated with the Gnome Desktop
- It has support for the RAW format
- Some basic editing capabilities

As stated on the comment above the elimination of Mono from the default install would be a huge bonus, less occupied space, and less conspiracy theories evolving Microsoft and .Net running about.

Comment: Can you give some evidence that removing Mono was a strong motivating factor? That's a controversial reason, and you've listed it first and treated it at length.

Comment: I don't think that was a strong motivating factor, in fact I think it had nothing to do. I said that would be a bonus, the free space on the install CD would be a real advantage. As for the religious conversations, they're just useless.

Comment: Is tomboy staying? This runs on mono too, I'm lead to believe...

Comment: Shotwell is just better. Better capabilities and a clear vision. It's going to be a great app very soon.

Comment: I don't think GNOME upstream had anything to do with that choice : both f-spot and shotwell are photo managers for GNOME, but they don't have any kind of special status in the GNOME project or platform.
One significant difference is that f-spot is hosted on GNOME infrastructure (git, bugzilla, etc.)

Comment: @Owais: A year later, Shotwell is still lacking in features compared to what f-spot was back then :(